# How to calculate the potential energy and acceleration in a fixed pulley

Tags: homework-and-exercises, potential-energy

This is my first post here so I want to give a disclaimer. I study in Slovenia so maybe my terminology won't be proper. Sorry in advance!
So I came accross an excersise that is giving me a lot of trouble. Here is how it goes:

Over a fixed pulley there is a string on which hangs a weight with the mass of 2kg. On the other side of the string there is a force which pulls the weight upwards. When the weight is pulled for 60cm it has 3J of kinetic energy. 
Questions:
a) In that moment how much is the potential energy of the weight and how much work does the pulling force do?
b) What is the acceleration of the weight?

So I got the a) question down but the b) is giving me trouble. How am I supposed to calculate the acceleration? Using $F=m\cdot a$ ? I'm pretty bad at physics and we got an exam soon so I can't ask my teacher. I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: If you know the distance, initial velocity anbd final velocity you can use one of the constant acceleration kinematic equations to find the acceleration.

Comment: Can you please type them out because I mostly got no idea what you said. Don't you need time to calculate the acceleration?

Comment: Does this link help you? http://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/1DKin/Lesson-6/Kinematic-Equations-and-Problem-Solving

Comment: If you know the work done, then you can find the force that did this work (work is force times distance). And with that force you should indeed be able to use Newton's 2nd law as you suggested

Comment: Thanks I'll do the maths and I'll post it here if it's correct

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you can't ask your teacher for help. Isn't it their *job* to help you learn?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Part a) the problem states that after the "pulling force" has provided 12 joules of potential energy there is an excess of provided energy so that the object has 3 extra joules of kinetic energy. Therefore the work done by the "pulling force" has to be 15 joules (not including losses due to friction).

Part b) we have to assume that the initial velocity of the weight (before any work was done) was zero. This simplifies the Newtonian equation $v^2-u^2=2as$ to $\frac{1}2v^2=as$. Multilply both sides of this equation by mass (m) to get an energy equation. Replace the $\frac{1}2mv^2$ with the 3 joules stated, the rearrange to get an acceleration equation; $a=\frac{3}{ms}$ .